# Passing pageable (spring data) in post request

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a rest API server which has the following API.
I have some other APIs, where i get pageable from `GET` requests. Here, I need to make a post request for passing the queryDto. So, I cannot pass the  `page=0?size=20` etc as url parameters.

I would like to know how to pass pageable as JSON object to a `POST` request

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/internal/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseList<Object> findObjects(@RequestBody QueryDto queryDto, Pageable pageable) {
    if (queryDto.isEmpty()) {
        throw new BadRequestException();
    }

    return someService.findObjectsByQuery(queryDto, pageable);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I Think that is not possible, at least not already provided by the framework.

The Spring has a `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` interface with an implementation called `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` that retrieves the request param value calling something like HttpServletRequest.getParameter. So, you can bind the Pageable instance passing the parameters "page" and "size" for GET and POST. So, the following code works:

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/test",method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String bindPage(Pageable page){
    return page.toString();
}
```

$ curl -X POST --data "page=10&size=50" http://localhost:8080/test

Return:
Page request [number: 10, size 50, sort: null]

But, if you pass an json nothing happens:

$ curl -X POST --data "{page:10&size:50}" http://localhost:8080/test

Return:
Page request [number: 0, size 20, sort: null]

Comment: If you put the page and size as query parameters it works fine for me.  See my answer.

Answer (score 12):

Spring Post method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/quickSearchAction", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody SearchList quickSearchAction(@RequestParam(value="userId") Long userId, 
                                          Pageable pageable) throws Exception {
    return searchService.quickSearchAction(userId, pageable);
}
```

Postman Example:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/actionSearch/quickSearchAction?
userId=4451&number=0&size=20&sort=titleListId,DESC
```

In above POST Pageable is used for Sorting and Pagination in Spring RESTful service. Use below syntax at URL.

number `0`, size `20`, Sort by field `titleListId` and direction `DESC`

All passing parameter internally recognizes by **Pageable** as Sorting / Pagination parameters as below

```
number - Page number

size - Page Size

sort - sort by(Order by)

direction - ASC / DESC
```

Updated:
Angular Example:
**CustomerComponent.ts** file

```
let resultDesignations = null;
let fieldName = "designationId";

this.customerService.getDesignations(fieldName, "DESC").subscribe(
  (data) => {
    resultDesignations = data;
  },
  (err) => {
    this.error(err.error);
  },
  () => {
    this.designations = resultDesignations;
  }
);//END getDesignations`
```

**CustomerService.ts**

```
getDesignations(fieldName: string, sortOrder: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:9876/api/getDesignations", {
      params: {
        sort: fieldName,sortOrder
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: how can we send these params from ajax javascript code .

Comment: In my case, number parameter does not work, I have to pass page param.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to work just fine for me if you continue to provide them as query parameters on the URL, and still post data in.

```
POST http://localhost:8080/xyz?page=2&size=50
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "filterABC": "data"
}
```

Spring seems to translate the page, size, sort etc. into the Pageable provided to the method on the way in.

Comment: This answer works perfectly. In my case I was doing a GET  request with a RequestBody and pageable. Supplying page and size as query params  allowed for the request to go through successfully.

Answer (score 1):

create a class that has the Pageable and QueryDto objects as members.  Then pass JSON in the post body of this new object.

for example,

```
public class PageableQueryDto
{
    private Pageable pageable;
    private QueryDto queryDto;

    ... getters and setters.
}
```

**Edit**
As noted in the comment below, you may need to implement the Pageable interface.
The result could be something like this:

```
public class PageableQueryDto implements Pageable
{
    private Pageable pageable;
    private QueryDto queryDto;

    ... getters and setters.

    ... Implement the Pageable interface.  proxy all calls to the
    ... contained Pageable object.

    ... for example
    public void blam()
    {
        pageable.blam();
    }

    ... or maybe
    public void blam()
    {
        if (pageable != null)
        {
            pageable.blam();
        }
        else
        {
            ... do something.
        }
}
```

Comment: seems a good solution. But, one doubt: Probably he need to expose some other interface for "Pageable" object, because  Pageable is a interface and the framework implementation does not have default constructor or setters for page and size. Dont you think?

Answer (score 1):

sample example

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/employees",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json",produces = "application/json")
ResponseEntity<Object> getEmployeesByPage(@RequestBody PageDTO page){
    //creating a pagable object with pagenumber and size of the page
    Pageable pageable= PageRequest.of(page.getPage(),page.getSize());
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED).body(employeeRegistryService.getEmployeesByPage(pageable));
}
```

In your case try to add pagination variables in QueryDTO 
create a Pageable object and pass it to service

I think that will solve :)

Answer (score 0):

**An updated answer for spring boot:**

`Pageable` supports the following url params:

- page - page number, where 0 is the first page
- size - page size
- sort - sort by field
- direction - ASC/DESC

E.g.

Sample GET URL:

> localhost:8080/users?page=2&size=10&sort=createdAt,DESC

```
@GetMapping("/users")
public ResponseEntity<?> getUsers(Pageable pageable) {
    try {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(userService.getUsers(pageable));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```